# Recovering KVM VMs when booting from mirrored host OS

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, data-recovery

Im running KVM on a Ubunutu 14.05 server. The server has 2 1.2TB drives which will each have 1 VM (elastic search nodes). I did a dd to clone the main OS and can boot from either disk without issue.

In the event that the primary OS drive goes down and I boot from the back up, will I have to do anything special to have the back up OS read the VMs? From my testing it seemed like it didn't.

Comment: And so it happened. :(

I rebooted the host and now the host can't see the VM. The xml files are there and everything looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the VM disk images available and have the VM definitions in place, it will work. Make sure you stay with the same distribution, because the way VMs get defined in different distros might vary.

Comment: OK I think I get what you mean. The entire stack will be Ubuntu

Comment: Not my choice of distribution for anything KVM, but I won't get into an argument over this

Comment: :) The selection is from above.